# Bootstrap - Navbar Toggler is expanding "upwards" instead of "downwards"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I try to expand my `navbar` with the `toggler-button`, the `navbar` is expanding upwards instead of downwards.

How can I change it, so it expands downwards?

[image: Navbar expanding "upwards"]

My complete code is in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/madev1/pen/NWrbwZN)

**HTML**

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    min-width: 350px;
}

.outline {
    border-left: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    border-right: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

header li a {
    font-family: "PFDINTextPro";
    color:#081352;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0.4;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    text-shadow:
    2px 2px white,
    2px -2px white,
    -2px 2px white,
    -2px -2px white;
}

header li a:hover {
  font-family: "PFDINTextPro-Medium";
  color:#081352;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7689F4;
  text-shadow:
    2px 2px white,
    2px -2px white,
    -2px 2px white,
    -2px -2px white;
}

header li a:active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7689F4;
  text-shadow:
    2px 2px white,
    2px -2px white,
    -2px 2px white,
    -2px -2px white;
}

.brandName {
    font-family: "Uni-Sans-Bold";
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    color: #081452 !important;
}

.brandNameSmall {
    font-family: "Uni-Sans-Bold";
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #081452 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navSection {
    min-width: 350px;
}

.navNoPaddingMargin {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


.navbar.navbar-1 .navbar-toggler-icon { 
  background-image: url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/953/953223.svg');
  border-color: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  }

.navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .buttonShoppingMobile {
  border-color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: red;
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  text-decoration: none;

}


.buttonShoppingLg {
  background-color: #FF5A6E;
}

.icon-background {
  color: #FF5A6E;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container order-2 order-lg-2 outline pl-lg-2 pr-lg-2 py-lg-5 pl-xl-5 pr-xl-5 py-xl-5">
    <div class="row navSection rowSectionNav align-items-center pr-sm-1 pl-sm-1 pr-md-5 pl-md-5">
        <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-1 navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white navNoPaddingMargin">
                <!-- link on smaller devices -->
                <a class="d-flex d-lg-none order-2 navbar-brand align-items-start brandNameSmall ml-3 mt-2" href="#">
                <!-- LOGO on smaller devices -->
                <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/2995/2995531.svg" width="27" height="27" class="d-inline-block d-lg-none align-top mr-2" alt="" loading="lazy">WavesLogo <span class="d-block d-lg-none" style="color: #FF5A6E;font-family: Uni-Sans-Bold; font-size: 1.6rem" >+</span></a>
                <!-- link on larger devices -->
                <a class="d-none d-lg-flex order-lg-1 navbar-brand align-items-start brandName ml-3 mt-2 mt-lg-0" href="#">
                <!-- LOGO on larger devices -->
                <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/2995/2995531.svg" width="40" height="40" class="d-none d-lg-inline-block align-top mr-2" alt="" loading="lazy">WavesLogo <span class="d-none d-lg-block" style="color: #FF5A6E;font-family: Uni-Sans-Bold; font-size: 1.6rem" >+</span></a>
                <button class="order-1 navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-icon" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <!-- <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> -->
                </button>
                <div class="nav collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-1" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="order-3 order-lg-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">
                        <a class="" href="#"></a>Cart
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is with order-* classes. Try removing them from the logo and the navbar-toggler-icon

Comment: Or change `order-lg-1` to `order-lg-3` to the element with id `navbarNav`

Comment: @madev, I correct your moving log, please don't forget to validate answer or upvote

Comment: @madev is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need `order-2` into :
`<div class="nav collapse navbar-collapse order-2 order-lg-1" id="navbarNav">`

Your logo problems is fixed with:

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .brandNameSmall{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  }
}
```

### Demo

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    min-width: 350px;
}

.outline {
    border-left: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    border-right: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

header li a {
    font-family: "PFDINTextPro";
    color:#081352;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0.4;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    text-shadow:
    2px 2px white,
    2px -2px white,
    -2px 2px white,
    -2px -2px white;
}

header li a:hover {
  font-family: "PFDINTextPro-Medium";
  color:#081352;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7689F4;
  text-shadow:
    2px 2px white,
    2px -2px white,
    -2px 2px white,
    -2px -2px white;
}

header li a:active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7689F4;
  text-shadow:
    2px 2px white,
    2px -2px white,
    -2px 2px white,
    -2px -2px white;
}

.brandName {
    font-family: "Uni-Sans-Bold";
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    color: #081452 !important;
}

.brandNameSmall {
    font-family: "Uni-Sans-Bold";
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #081452 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navSection {
    min-width: 350px;
}

.navNoPaddingMargin {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


.navbar.navbar-1 .navbar-toggler-icon { 
  background-image: url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/953/953223.svg');
  border-color: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  }

.navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .brandNameSmall{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container order-2 order-lg-2 outline pl-lg-2 pr-lg-2 py-lg-5 pl-xl-5 pr-xl-5 py-xl-5">
    <div class="row navSection rowSectionNav align-items-center pr-sm-1 pl-sm-1 pr-md-5 pl-md-5">
        <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-1 navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white navNoPaddingMargin">
                <!-- link on smaller devices -->
                <a class="d-flex d-lg-none order-2 navbar-brand align-items-start brandNameSmall ml-3 mt-2" href="#">
                <!-- LOGO on smaller devices -->
                <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/2995/2995531.svg" width="27" height="27" class="d-inline-block d-lg-none align-top mr-2" alt="" loading="lazy">WavesLogo <span class="d-block d-lg-none" style="color: #FF5A6E;font-family: Uni-Sans-Bold; font-size: 1.6rem" >+</span></a>
                <!-- link on larger devices -->
                <a class="d-none d-lg-flex order-lg-1 navbar-brand align-items-start brandName ml-3 mt-2 mt-lg-0" href="#">
                <!-- LOGO on larger devices -->
                <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/2995/2995531.svg" width="40" height="40" class="d-none d-lg-inline-block align-top mr-2" alt="" loading="lazy">WavesLogo <span class="d-none d-lg-block" style="color: #FF5A6E;font-family: Uni-Sans-Bold; font-size: 1.6rem" >+</span></a>
                <button class="order-1 navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-icon" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <!-- <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> -->
                </button>
                <div class="nav collapse navbar-collapse order-2 order-lg-1" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-nowrap" href="#">Link4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="order-3 order-lg-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn buttonShoppingMobile">
                        <a class="" href="#"></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. The logo is now in the correct place. but I now have the problem, that there is also a button on the top left of the menu, which does get pushed down when the menu collapses. I changed my code above so the button got visible as it was not in my first post. How can I achieve that the button stays in line with the logo?

Comment: Please valid and create a new question or edit your question.